# Applescript: Getting Information from Website

Tags: applescript, itunes

Trying to get a single bit of information from this website (https://songbpm.com/one-of-these-nights-eagles) as part of an AppleScript to autofill the BPM on each of my tracks in iTunes. The script takes the track, opens up the webpage, and now I just need to get the first BPM listed (in this case 110) and send it back to my script.

How do I do this?

Comment: Rather than scrape an HTML website, you might be better using `curl` and an API https://getsongbpm.com/api

Comment: I fear I may need to do that, but just want to keep it fairly simple at the moment with Applescript

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using this bit of code, thanks entirely to http://www.cubemg.com/how-to-extract-information-from-a-website-using-applescript/:

```
to getInput(theClass, num)

tell application "Safari"

    set input to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1 -- uses JavaScript to set the variable input to the information we want

    return input 

end tell
end getInput 
set urlBPM to getInput("title", 3)
```